# How to get click outside the dialog box even if setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean) is set to false

Tags: android

I am implementing dialog in android and I want my dialog not to be dismissed if user click outside the dialog box but I want Click events of outside the dialog when the dialog is displayed.

Comment: Are you using normal dialog or an activity as a dialog !

Answer (score 0):

Override onTouchEvent() of dialog and check for action type. if the action type is `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE` that means user is interacting outside the dialog region. So in this case, you can dismiss your dialog or decide what you wanted to perform :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
    System.out.println("Touched outside the dialog");
   }  
   return false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the touch happened outside the dialog or a view, you have to override `DispatchTouchEvent()` in the activity and check in that method. Like : 

 Create an interface to trigger the touchOutSide like below:

```
/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a touch event has occurred outside a formerly specified view.
 * See {@link #setOnTouchOutsideViewListener(View, OnTouchOutsideViewListener)}
 */
public interface OnTouchOutsideViewListener {
    /**
     * Called when a touch event has occurred outside a given view.
     *
     * @param view  The view that has not been touched.
     * @param event The MotionEvent object containing full information about the event.
     */
    void onTouchOutside(View view, MotionEvent event);
}
```

Suppose if you have base Activity you can put all the code in it, or else use it in activity.

Override `dispatchTouchEvent()` which will be triggered for all the touch happens on screen. Here we will get the touched **x and y** on the screen, so you have to get the views **x and y** and check if this point is within the touch.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Notify touch outside listener if user tapped outside a given view
        if (mOnTouchOutsideViewListener != null && mTouchOutsideView != null
                && mTouchOutsideView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            mTouchOutsideView.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);
            if (!viewRect.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY())) {
                mOnTouchOutsideViewListener.onTouchOutside(mTouchOutsideView, ev);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

For setting touch outside listener and removing it, create methods in activity like below :

```
/**
 * Sets a listener that is being notified when the user has tapped outside a given view. To remove the listener,
 * call {@link #removeOnTouchOutsideViewListener()}.
 * <p/>
 * This is useful in scenarios where a view is in edit mode and when the user taps outside the edit mode shall be
 * stopped.
 *
 * @param view
 * @param onTouchOutsideViewListener
 */
public void setOnTouchOutsideViewListener(View view, OnTouchOutsideViewListener onTouchOutsideViewListener) {
    mTouchOutsideView = view;
    mOnTouchOutsideViewListener = onTouchOutsideViewListener;
}

public void removeOnTouchOutsideViewListener() {
    mTouchOutsideView = null;
    mOnTouchOutsideViewListener = null;
}
```

So finally what you should do is, pass the top most parent view to the `setOnTouchOutsideViewListener()` in `onCreate()` of activity.In your case after `dialog.show()`, pass dialogs parent layout. Like :

```
View detectTouchOutsideThisView = findViewById(R.id.parent_view);
setOnTouchOutsideViewListener(detectTouchOutsideThisView, new OnTouchOutsideViewListener() {
    void onTouchOutside(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        //If touch outside this will be triggered
    }
});
```